# Problem with placeholder value and searching on categories (ignoring keywords) - SuperSearch

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I need the user to be able to search against two category groups: one for states, and the other for job type, i.e., accounting, HR, etc.

Two problems:

First, I try to use a placeholder value for my  fields:

```
<select name="category[]">
<option val="">Select Category</option>
{exp:channel:categories channel="jobs" 
category_group="5" disable="category_fields"
style="linear"}
    {exp:super_search:variables}
        <option val="{category_url_title}">{category_name}</option>
    {/exp:super_search:variables}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

(This is one of them.) The blank value ends up passing 'Select+Category' in to the URL.

Secondly, I need to ignore the keywords field altogether. I tried adding a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="keywords" value="">
```

But that doesn't matter.

My search results page is yielding incorrect results because it thinks the keywords value is "", which is like "any".

Try submitting the form: http://usesi.savagedevserver.com/jobs

[image: Screencap]

Comment: The correct attribute for the `option` element is `value`, not `val`. Try using `<option value="...">`.

Comment: What version of Super Search are you using? What version of EE are you using?

Comment: I fixed value vs. val. EE 2.7, SuperSearch 2.1.3.

Answer (score 3):

For the first issue try changing `<option val="">Select Category</option>` to `<option>Select Category</option>`... specifically removing the `val=""`.

---

I took a look at the [**Solspace Supersearch docs**](http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/search/#keywords) and I don't see that keyword is required. So try taking it out.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the val parameter from the option solved the first problem. However, it's still returning all results because it thinks keywords="".

Comment: Not having a `value` attribute in an `<option>` will submit the text inside the `<option></option>` itself. If you want to submit an empty string, use the attribute `value=""` instead.

Comment: Also, if you don't have a "keywords" field in your search form, no search will be done for "keywords", i.e. `&keywords=` shouldn't show up in your URL. Your results should be filtered by your selected categories only based on your image above. Make sure both select fields have `name="category[]"`.

Comment: I removed <input type="hidden" name="keywords"> - but the problem happens with or without this field.

Comment: @Solspace = please see notes below - I've removed the keywords field and corrected category_indicator. This site launches soon, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have the search form looking better, try looking at your search results tag. Specifically,

> **[category[]](http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/search/#category)** This field allows users to search on categories. Default behaviour is
>   searching on category names. To switch this to category ID or URL
>   titles, use the category_indicator parameter in the Results tag

Do you have the category_indicator parameter setup on your results tag?

Comment: I've added the category_indicator, but am getting the same result.

Comment: Please post an example of a URL that is failing so we can see what the search form is passing to the results page.

Comment: See http://usesi.savagedevserver.com/jobs and try a search.